# Why do we use Async in login process even we have to wait for the results?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Can someone explain why async process required even we have to wait for the results in network calls?

Comment: Because Network and IO operation should be done a worker thread in android . Either you wait for result or Use a Callback interface. Waiting for result here is not means that the  UI thread is blocked. Read some of the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception).

Comment: @ADM Thanks for you response

Answer (score 1):

Because if we run network calls on the main thread, it would block the user from using the application. The main thread would be blocked.

If the main thread is not responsive to user events like touch , it would lead to ANR( Application Not Responding ).